# Can't find local json within action reduxjs

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to access a local json file within a redux action, but for some reason it can't seem to find the file. My question is, when the action is executed is it executed at the relative path of the built app.bundle? New to javascript and redux.

I'm running the following:

```
const jsonFile = require('../json-files/'.concat(file).concat('.json'));
```

From a file at: project/src/main/actions/ActionScript.js

With jsons at: project/src/main/json-files/[file is here]

app.bundle.js is at project/bin/app.bundle.js

Getting Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '../json-files/file.json'

Relative pathing with that syntax works in other files (i.e. components) but for some reason doesn't work within the action.

Anything helps. Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't the path be `const jsonFile = require('../deal-jsons/'.concat(file).concat('.json'));` ?

Comment: @palsrealm sorry made a typo. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Redux Actions should not perform any side effects, such as asynchronous calls or Input/Output.

You will need some middleware to do that job, such as `redux-thunk`, `redux-saga` or `redux-observable`...

Comment: Yes I know that should be how it works, but I'm in the development stage, so I just need to be able to dynamically look at local files. If I create an action that dispatches after the request is made, it will still fail. Looking for a way to make this work in the time being. Thank you for the comment though.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the line of code to:
`const jsonFile = require('../json-files/'.concat(file);` and check if it works?